# laravel rest api upload file to server

Tags: php, android, laravel, rest, base64

Am creating a REST api with laravel that allows a user to select an image file from their android device, then upload it to the server. The mage is converted to base64 before it's sent to the server alongside other parameters. I want to convert this base64 to a file and store it on the server then generate a link that can be used to access it. here is what i have tried so far and it doesnt work: I have already created a symlink to storage

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
        $location = new Location();
        $location->name = $request->location_name;
        $location->latitude = $request->latitude;
        $location->longitude = $request->longitude;

        $location->saveOrFail();

        $provider = new Provider();
        $provider->name = $request->provider_name;
        $provider->location_id = $location->id;
        $provider->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $provider->description = $request->description;
        $provider->image = request()->file(base64_decode($request->encoded_image))->store('public/uploads');


        $provider->saveOrFail();

        return json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'message'=>'Provider created successfully'));


}
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/Intervention/image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already commented by Amando, you can use the [Intervention/Image](https://github.com/Intervention/image) package, having used it for many years I can say it will do what you want and very well.

What I would also add though, is you may also want to consider, whether you indeed need to store it as a file at all.

Depending on what it will be used for, and the size etc, you could consider storing it in the DB itself, along with any other information. This removes the dependency on a file server, and will make your application much more flexible with regards to infrastructure requirements.

At the end of the day, files are just data, if you will always get the file when you get the other data, reduce the steps and keep related data together.

Either way, hope you get it sorted :)

Comment: thanks for this. does intervention allow me to store it in the DB?

Comment: It will do yes, effectively it helps with parsing images, adjusting them, and any other thing you can thing of. It will even take care of encoding the image so you dont need to worry about dropping it to base64 :)

Comment: thaks for this. i went through the library and finally grasped it's ropes. marking this as accepted

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, once you get your head around it, you can make a huge improvement in how you handle images. It changed my life :)